# How do i use numpy to return an array that sums up data from a csv file where the first column contains strings & the others contain float using

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a CSV file that contains the power supply per plant for a month, I want to sum up the total supply per hour for each plant using NumPy and still maintain the dimensions.
below is an example of the data in the CSV file.

```
PLANT  1.00hrs  2.00hrs  ...  22.00hrs  23.00hrs  24.00hrs
AFAM IV - V     30.0     30.0  ...      50.0      50.0      50.0
AFAM IV - V     30.0     20.0  ...      50.0      30.0      30.0
AFAM IV - V     30.0     30.0  ...      50.0      50.0      50.0
AFAM IV - V    116.0    117.2  ...     166.1     170.6     164.6
AFAM IV - V     50.0     50.0  ...      48.0      48.0      50.0
```

here is what i have tried doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pycharmProject\\NESI_REPORT_JAN.csv'

pdf = pd.read_csv(path)
print(np.sum(np.sum(pdf)))
```

which gives me the following outcome:

```
PLANT       AFAM IV - VAFAM IV - VAFAM IV - VAFAM IV - VAF...
1.00hrs                                              111962.9
2.00hrs                                              106835.2
3.00hrs                                             101608.21
4.00hrs                                               99191.9
5.00hrs                                             102670.56
6.00hrs                                             112298.41
```

i have also tried this:

```
import numpy as np

path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pycharmProject\\NESI_REPORT_JAN.csv'

data = np.genfromtxt(path, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
newdata = np.array(data)

print(np.sum(data, axis=0, keepdims=True))
```

please how do i sum the hours for each plant  using numpy arrays with the original dimentions.

Comment: `df.groupby('PLANT').sum()`?

Comment: please could you explain how im to apply this?     df.groupby('PLANT').sum()

Comment: I mean `pdf.groupby('PLANT').sum()`. Use it after `read_csv`

Comment: Why `numpy`?  Why not stick with one or more of `pandas` aggregating methods?

Comment: i wish to do a rowise summation of the data as well and im not sure how to do that using pandas

Comment: Yes, pandas can dot it: `df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you Very Much. It Worked. i will use pandas to handle the rest of the work

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt(fname = 'data.csv', delimiter ='  ', skip_header = 1)
#skip_header ->     The number of lines to skip at the beginning of the file.
data = np.nan_to_num(data, nan = 0)

#now you have a normal np.array
row_sum = np.sum(data, axis = 0)
```